# Why a python method not returning?

Tags: python, methods

I have a destroy() method which is called before my thread is coming down.

```
def destroy(self):
    self.logger.debug("Instance is being destroyed")
    //do stuff
    self.logger.debug("Instance has been destroyed")
```

This is the code from where it is called:

```
if (__name__ == '__main__'):
try:        
    instance = device_instance()             
        while True:
            //do stuff
            if input_string == 'destroy':
                instance.destroy()
                logger.debug("Back in main after destroying")
                break
            else:
                //do stuff
            time.sleep(.100)
except Exception, ex:
    logger.debug("Exception occurred" + str(ex))
except:
    logger.debug("Unhandled exception occurred")
```

Now when I run it, the problem is I see logging statements "Instance is being destroyed" and "Instance has been destroyed" and I don't see "Back in main after destroying". That means my destroy() is never returning. I tried adding explicit return statement, still the same problem. If I add sys.exit(0) to destroy() at the end, it does raise exception which is eventually caught in main.
What could be the issue?

Comment: You don't need the parenthesis around `__name__ == '__main__'`; in fact, they look wrong.

Comment: It works both ways - with or without parenthesis.

Comment: All,Thank you for your help. I found out one of my peer started calling destroy of my thread hoping it would stop my thread but actually I had a seperate stop method which would call destroy and then thread would exit. Blunders of pair programming I guess!

Comment: +1 Vote close as OP has found the answer and there was no a real question involved.  @quest I'm glad you found the error.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking at the same logger?

Comment: the logging statements in __main__ are actually using same logger(instance.logger)

Answer (score 1):

Is your log level above to debug?  Try with `print`

Also, try adding a log before the call.

Comment: I tried with print too. And I also added logging before the call. It has the same result.

Comment: Did the log before showed? You are probably ( some how I don't quite get )  destroying the logger too. Try addint `exit` after the call and see if that's cached too

Answer (score 1):

I think we'll need a bit more information than this -- probably about the context of 'do something' and `input_string`

I put this into a piece of code:

```
import logging                                                                                          
import time                                                                                             

logger = logging.getLogger('')                                                                          

class device_instance(object):                                                                          

    def destroy(self):                                                                                  
        self.logger.warning('Instance is being destroyed')                                              
        # do stuff                                                                                      
        self.logger.warning('Instance is destroyed')                                                    

input_strings = ['one', 'two', 'destroy']                                                               

if (__name__ == '__main__'):                                                                            
    logging.basicConfig()                                                                               
    try:                                                                                                
        instance = device_instance()                                                                    
        instance.logger = logger                                                                        

        gen = input_strings.__iter__()                                                                  

        while True:                                                                                     
            #do stuff                                                                                   
            try:                                                                                        
                input_string = gen.next()                                                               
            except StopIteration:                                                                       
                input_string = 'destroy'                                                                

            if input_string == 'destroy':                                                               
                instance.destroy()                                                                      
                logger.warning("Back in main after destroying")                                         
                break                                                                                   
            else:                                                                                       
                time.sleep(.100)                                                                        
    except:                                                                                             
        logger.exception("Unhandled exception occurred")
```

This outputs what you'd expect:

```
WARNING:root:Instance is being destroyed                                                                    
WARNING:root:Instance is destroyed                                                                          
WARNING:root:Back in main after destroying
```

So something else is at play, I think.